# Using JNLP File to launch an application

Tags: java, jsp, jnlp

I have a jsp page as:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Try in JNLP</title>

        <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

        <script>    
             var dir = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            var url = dir + "try.jnlp";
            deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
        </script>
        <noscript>JavaScript is required for this page.</noscript>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and have a jnlp file as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/try/" href="try.jnlp">

    <information>
        <title>TRY JNLP</title>
        <vendor>TRY JNLP</vendor>
    </information>

    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->

        <jar href="TryJNLP.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc name="Try JNLP"  main-class="tryjnlp.TRYJNLPApp">
     </application-desc>

    <update check="background"/>

</jnlp>
```

All jars are in their respective directories but when I double click the jnlp file it shows me an error saying :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/application/SingleFrameApplication
```

with the its full error stack.

where as if I simply runs my swing application(TryJNLP.jar) by double clicking, it runs perfectly.

Please help me.

Comment: @Ankur: please list the jars that are 'in their respective directories' and also where the directories are and the content of your META-INF/context.xml

Comment: Jar name is same as mentioned: **TryJNLP.jar** and its manifest.mf file is
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_23 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
SplashScreen-Image: resources/images/splash.png
Main-Class: SwingSet2`
one more thing (my bad) I changed the main-class property of .jnlp file too to SwingSet2`
even then exception is occuring 
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SwingSet2**

Comment: The JNLP file is invalid.  Check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: `SplashScreen-Image: resources/images/splash.png`  That type of splash does not work in JWS, which has its own mechanism for displaying splash screens.  The splash is specified in the JNLP file, and cannot be in a Jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this code seems to depend on JSR 296, it will be necessary to add the: `ApplicationFramework-<version>.jar` to the run-time class-path of the application (in the resources section of the JNLP).

Comment: where to write please explain in detail.

Comment: yeah ok 
I am asking for **ApplicationFramework-<version>.jar**